# Amazon SNS text message not being received by some phones

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

If I send a message to my own phone, it gets received properly.  If I send it to my wife or son's phone, the message does not get received. Despite this, the SNS dashboard says that the messages were properly sent.  I hope I'm missing something, but at this point, I don't feel like I can use SNS for customer facing apps if all the feedback I get says it worked fine, but I can't guarantee that the users actually receive a text.  This is the first time I've used SNS in this way.  Is this expected behavior or am I maybe missing something?

Comment: Have you exceeded the spending limit? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sns-sms-spending-limit-increase/

Comment: No, though I have a $1 spending limit, I've only sent a total of about 20 messages and I can consistently send them to my own phone successfully.

Comment: If SNS monitoring says all were delivered then it is likely blocked at some point before its being received. Its probably worth raising to AWS support as they should be able to identify why it is not sending

Comment: I just ended up using twilio instead.  Had it up and running in like 10 minutes and it works exactly as expected.  It even has a dashboard showing the status of each individual message with timestamps.